# parent.location.reload in iframe not working IE

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, access-denied

I need refresh in parent site / refresh my browser when I click testing. I have source index.php:

```
<iframe id="test" src="/careertest/q.php"></iframe>
```

and in q.php:

```
<a href="#" onclick="parent.location.reload(true);">testing</a>
```

Its working in FF LAtest version + Chrome but not working in IE 9.

He said "script70 :Permission denied."

I am already change

```
parent.location.reload(true)
```

with:

```
window.parent.location =window.parent.location.href;
```

or

```
document.domain=document.location.href;
```

but still not working...

Comment: Tested, working fine for me. Can you provide a test page?

Comment: Also work for me. Maybe you have wrong security settings?

Comment: hi thanks for quick replay http://kimpuler.com/error.jpg this ...i am use developer tool ( f12 ) in IE9 and cannot refresh...i think you try in localhost and fast view  so not know its refresh page or not...try  with insert  big image...so loading long

Comment: Also work for me. Maybe you have wrong security settings? -– neworld -> can you tell me more please...actually i am latest use OS windows 7:(...thanks...

Comment: my client also still can't refresh in IE8 :(

Comment: already reset setting in IE9 but still not working :(

Comment: this now http://kimpuler.com/error2.jpg screenshot error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function

```
function reloadParentPage() {
    var selfUrl = unescape(parent.window.location.pathname);
    parent.location.reload(true);

    parent.window.location.replace(selfUrl);

    parent.window.location.href = selfUrl;
}
```

Comment: hi...thanks Chamika..your function working also...and also my code javascript in above working in simple code http://kimpuler.com/mencoba ...but not working in my site/ full code .but i think got problem with " cache "...its possible ?.

Comment: THIS CODE function aoove WORKING, i think got problem with my meta cache , its possible ?

Comment: what is your parent page and child page url?

Comment: parent page index.php , in this(index.php ) contain iframe src="g.php" name='test' , this sample illustration http://kimpuler.com/mencoba

Comment: hi..chamika ...this demo http://fremont.edu/careertest ,you can try entry form then click , when i click i put js onclick ="parent.window.location.reload(true)" ..its working in FF + Chrome ..but not in IE9...any issue ?

Comment: this code will solve the problem. `window.open(unescape(parent.window.location.pathname), "_top");`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "window" after parent.

```
parent.window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: hi...thanks for replay ..actually your code working ...but i got problem with my codes ...:( i think about 
"cache" its possible ? i am try "enter" in address browser then can effect ...

Comment: WORKING this code js above  ..so sorry ..i am try simple code in http://kimpuler.com/mencoba but when i try in my code got problem...its possible about cache problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE, Chrome and Firefox and may be others

```
window.top.location.reload();
```