# reload parent window ie9 access denied

Tags: window, internet-explorer-9, parent, reload

IE9 won't let me reload parent window from inside iframe. Here is my code

```
  if(result != 0)
  {
     window.location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
     alert(alert_arr.fail_document_save);
  }
  return true;
```

IE9 outputs: SCRIPT70: Permission denied

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(result != 0)
  {
    var selfUrl = unescape(parent.window.location.pathname);

    parent.window.location.replace(selfUrl);

    parent.window.location.href = selfUrl;
  }
  else
  {
     alert(alert_arr.fail_document_save);
  }
  return true;
```

As per [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546013/169334)

Comment: No, same result. Permission denied