# How to refresh parent page when i call iframe?

Tags: php

When successful submitting edit page  through iframe, I want to refresh parent page.

**Iframe code:**

```
<iframe id="docframe" name="docframe" src="includedocinfo.php" 
       height="550" width="900px" scrolling="auto"  frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent location for reload parent from iframe

```
parent.location.reload();
```

[Just see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545633/parent-location-reload-in-iframe-not-working-ie)

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put. I mean parent page or edit page.